# Как использовать функцию preg_replace в данном коде? Нужно чтобы каждые 'к' в $args[0] воспринималась кодои как 000

Tags: php

здесь код в котором мне нужно чтобы каждые 'к'  в аргс[0] воспринимались ботом как 000]

```php
if (mb_substr($msg, 0, 7) == 'рейтинг') {
    if ($args[0] == '') {
        $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, " Ваш рейтинг: " . number_format($user->rating, 0, '', '.'));
    } else {
        if (!is_numeric($args[0])) {
            $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, "Вы можете купить минимум 1 ");
        } else {
            $raticost = $args[0] * 150;
            if ($user->balance <= $raticost) {
                $vk->sendMessage($peer_id, 'Недостаточно средств. Стоимость 1 : 150$');
            } else {
                $user->balance = $user->balance - $raticost;
                $user->rating = $user->rating + $args[0];
                R::store($user);
                $vk->sendMessage($peer_id,
                    "Вы купили " . number_format($args[0], 0, '', '.') . '  за ' . number_format($raticost, 0,
                        '',
                        '.') . "$\n Баланс: " . number_format($user->balance, 0, '',
                        '.') . '$  Рейтинг: ' . number_format($user->rating, 0, '', '.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не вставляйте скрин вместо кода. Это очень плохая практика. Такой код нельзя скопировать и проверить а надо переписывать вручную.

Comment: просто у меня все переносы поплыли, ладно сорри;)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help справка по форматированию. Ничего сложного, после её изучения вас перестанут минусовать =)